# jQuery disable button on page by classname

Tags: jquery, magento, button

I need a function to disable this button:

```
<button type="submit" 
        title="Place Order" 
        class="button btn-checkout" 
        onclick="review.save();"><span><span>Place Order</span></span>
</button>
```

I was thinking about calling it before the review.save in the onclick.
Should I remove the onclick attribute and make it a click event handler and do it there?

Some customers are pressing the button twice and getting duplicate orders and charges.
Should I disable the submit of the form as well? How is the best way to handle this? This is a Magento One Page Checkout.

Comment: Again, I ask, are these the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.btn-checkout').click(function(e) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        review.save();
    });
});
```

on `save` callback (depending on what it actually do) you can enable the button again.

Answer (score 3):

Old school works nicely here.

```
<button type="submit" 
        title="Place Order" 
        class="button btn-checkout" 
        onclick="review.save();this.disabled = 'disabled';"><span><span>Place Order</span></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable the onclick ;)

`$('.btn-checkout').attr('onclick','return false');`

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button by setting the disabled attribute.

```
$(".btn-checkout").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button by running:

```
$(".btn-checkout").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is Magento it is prototype and not jquery. Therefore:

```
$$('.button').each(function(elmt) {
elmt.observe('click', function(ev) {
        ev.target.disabled='disabled';
});
});
```

That should put disabled-once-clicked on all of the buttons on the page.